# Value Of $\pi$ obtained using limits!

Tags: limits, circles, area, pi, polygons

What i thought was simple, a circle can be formed by increasing the number of sides of regular polygon( like pentagons, hexagons, etc ) up to infinity by keeping the distance between the center and the side constant.

it is an another way to say that a circle is a polygon with infinite number of sides.

the figure is below
[image]

let $AO=BO=r$

since it is a regular polygon, hence 
$$ar(AOB)= \frac 12 AB\times OC= r^2\times \frac {AC}r \times \frac{OC}r$$

since $sin \theta= AC/r, cos \theta = OC/r$
$$\therefore ar(AOB) = r^2sin\theta cos\theta= \frac{r^2}2sin\phi$$

since it is an n sided regular polygon hence the total area of this polygon is $$ar(polygon)= n\frac{r^2}2 sin \phi$$
and we know that because it is a regular polygon hence $\phi = 360^0/n$ 
$$ar(polygon)= \frac{nr^2}2sin{\frac {360^0}n}$$

now i told you earlier that the number of sides is tending towards infinity which will tends to  make the polygon a circle, hence

$$ar(circle) = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{nr^2}2sin{\frac {360^0}n} $$

and we know that area of a circle is $\pi r^2$

$$\therefore \pi r^2= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{nr^2}2sin{\frac {360^0}n}
\implies \pi= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}2sin{\frac {360^0}n}\ldots (1)$$

so the value of $\pi$ is above.

the equation  1 says that when n will become larger and larger the value of the function will become closer to the value of $\pi$ i.e. 3.14 (approx.).

Do you feel it is wrong? Can this thing be improved?

and yes the [Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yhl5tmdvbg)

thanks in advance.....

Comment: This is correct and it's because $\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\sin x}x=1}$ in radians.

Comment: What you have done is not useful since we *don't* know how to calculate sin(360/n) easily.  Perhaps if your polygons were 4 sided, 8-sided, 16-sided, etc, you could come up with a expression involving trig identities which are *easy" to calculate.  Even simpler, you can unravel your polygons into triangles and thence rearrange them into strip which you can easily calculate the area based upon the perimeter length of the circle and the radius.

Comment: Archimedes did this in ancient Greece.

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote, the area of the polygon is given by $$A_n=\frac{nr^2}2\sin{(\frac {2\pi}n})$$ Now, for large values of $n$, consider Taylor series around $x=0$ $$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ and replace $x=\frac {2\pi}n$ $$\sin({\frac {2\pi}n})=\frac{2 \pi }{n}-\frac{4 \pi ^3}{3 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ which makes $$A_n=\pi  r^2-\frac{2 \pi ^3 }{3
   n^2}r^2+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ and, as expected, the limit is approached from below.